# Delta query on user objects with filter, not supported?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to track the changes on AAD user objects using the query like below. 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$filter=accountEnabled eq true

Unfortunately I got an error Request_UnsupportedQuery in Graph Explorer. Is this only unsupported for *delta* query? I can use the same filter as below. 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=accountEnabled eq true

Any reason why MSFT graph does not support this in delta query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It supports `$filter`, but the only supported `$filter` expression is for tracking changes on a specific object: `$filter=id+eq+{value}`.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0#odata-query-parameters

[image]

Comment: Yes. `$filter` is limited support in User:delta